# MySQL Decimal query efficiency for different number of digits

Tags: mysql, decimal

I am trying to implement a table with entry as Decimal data type using MySQL. In the link (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html), it says that when I am using decimal to store a number that has 9 or less decimal digits, regardless of the number of digits being 7, 8 or 9, the storage space will be 4 bytes.

However, I am curious if any sql queries will take different amount of time if the decimal type number has different number of digits.

Since it take same 4 bytes, it should be same? Or would there be any difference?

Comment: This question is too broad in it's current form. In general a 1 byte difference in storage size has negligible effect on execution time. For small datasets it does not matter, for huge datasets.. well if this is the last thing you can do, I will bow in front of you. As an extra, comparing 4 bytes with 4 bytes is the same when there are 7 and 9 digits long decimal is stored on those bytes.

Comment: @Pred thank you for your answer, I was just curious and I just wanted to design a system while following the best practices.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, yes that is the storage size, not the execution time. FYI, the storage size is same with 4 bytes.

Comment: The best practice is to design a system which fulfils the business requirement and be able to run on the hardware you have. You can do premature optimization, but this kind of micro optimization is not really necessary in most cases. Use the data type which best fits to your data. If you need that 4 digit precision and you are in the 100 thousands range, decimal(10,4) is fine.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález its never 10 or more because Decimals are stored in a way that for every 9 digits it takes 4 bytes and the remaining ones take different number of bytes in this case 7, 8, 9 all take 4 bytes. Look at the table on the link for further clarification. Thanks though!

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález just for the example of 30 digits, it will be stored in 4(9 digits) + 4(9 digits) + 4(9 digits) + 2(3 digits) = 14 bytes. Hence, it is never 10 or more. 10 or more will be divided into blocks of digits less or equal to 9.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález okay sorry for causing the misunderstanding too then! Since we all understand this issue, I guess we are good! :)

Comment: What kind of value is it?  Perhaps `FLOAT` (4 bytes) or `DOUBLE` (8 bytes) would be a better choice?

Comment: Use `DECIMAL` for money; use `DOUBLE` for scientific stuff.

Comment: @RickJames Yup, I am using it for money and that's why Im sticking with Decimal!

Comment: If you don't need decimal places, then `INT` or `BIGINT` may be adequately big and more efficient.  If you do need decimals, the use `DECIMAL`.

Comment: Example:  `DECIMAL(11,2)` has 9 digits (4 bytes) to left of decimal point, and 2 to right (1 more byte), for a total of 5 bytes.  The next 'smaller' size would be `DECIMAL(8,2)` at 3+1=4 bytes.

Comment: @RickJames I am using it for dollars ($) and I need to take care of cents too which means that I need support for decimal places. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html) says:

> Values for DECIMAL (and NUMERIC) columns are represented using a
>   binary format that packs nine decimal (base 10) digits into four
>   bytes. Storage for the integer and fractional parts of each value are
>   determined separately. Each multiple of nine digits requires four
>   bytes, and the “leftover” digits require some fraction of four bytes.

It will depend on your CPU and your hardware configuration. Modern CPU's are smart enough and if you are not doing some really big calculations it should not affect the performance much. In case you are using it in a OLTP then it is not going to affect the performance very much. However in case of OLAP it might create some performance bottlenecks. But that is for something which involves really complex calculations.

Also just to add, prior to MySQL 5.0.3 decimal datatype was stored in format of string but later on with release of MySQL 5.1 and later the DECIMAL type is stored in a [binary format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal#Fixed-point_packed_decimal) so if we are not doing very complex calculations it should not affect the performance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me research on what OLTP and OLAP is haha. Btw what are you trying to say with the documentation? I read the documentation thoroughly before asking this question and it doesn't seem to be related to your answer.

Comment: @seokhoonlee:- Its just to highlight the point which I updated later i.e, the decimal datatype is now stored in binary format. Sorry for the confusion.